# Line Commutated Inverter

Tags: power-electronics, inverter, converter, thyristor

This is the circuit diagram for a Line Commutated Inverter which I came across in my power electronics book.

[image: Circuit diagram for line commutated inverter]

The input and output voltage waveforms are give below:

[image: Input and output voltage waveforms for the above circuit]

My logic says that from π to 2π, the thyristors T1 and T2 
must be reverse biased due to the -ve half cycle of input AC voltage. But it can be seen from the waveforms that this is not the case. Please explain how T1 and T2 are conducting from π to 2π.

Comment: Vba is positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse bias only applies to thyrisors when there is no current flow. Thyrisors are current control devices and if current through them is less than holding current then it turns in blocking mode. 
In above graph current through thyrisors are not zero so what ever voltage the supply takes the same voltage is taken to output .

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the given diagram it is assumed that the inductor in the load will try to maintain the current without much ripples..This inductor induced voltage keeps T1 and T2 on during negative half cycle